# i need to disable dates on react fullcalendar 3 months from now and 3 months ago

Tags: reactjs

This is my code

```
const handleSelectAllow = (selectInfo) => {
const currentDate = new Date();
const selectedDate = selectInfo.start;
const threeMonthsAgo = new Date();
threeMonthsAgo.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - 3);
const threeMonthsFromNow = new Date();
threeMonthsFromNow.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 3);

if (selectedDate >= threeMonthsAgo && selectedDate <= threeMonthsFromNow) {
  setIsAlertShown(false);
  return true;
} else if (!isAlertShown) {
  alert('Date selection is not allowed. Please select a date within the range of three months ago and three months from now.');
  setIsAlertShown(true);
  return false;
}
```

};

This is my calendar

```
            <FullCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          // headerToolbar={{
          //   left: 'prev,next today',
          //   center: 'title',
          //   right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
          // }}
          selectAllow={handleSelectAllow}
          selectLongPressDelay={null}
          initialView="dayGridMonth"
          editable={false}
          selectable={true}
          showNonCurrentDates={false}
          selectMirror={true}
          events={allEvents}
          select={handleDateClick}
          eventContent={renderEventContent}
          eventDidMount={eventDidMount}
          eventWillUnmount={eventWillUnmount}
        />
```

The issue tha i am facing now is the alert is only shown for the 1st time when the date is not in range if i set the setIsAlertShown(true) the alert shows when i hower over the calendar which is why i have used setIsAlertShown. Any fixes for this.This is my fullcalendar version  "@fullcalendar/react": "^6.1.5",